# context not updated in useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I have a context

```
const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    
    let sharedState: AppContextInterface = {
        isLoggedIn: isLoggedIn,
        setIsLoggedIn: setIsLoggedIn,
    }
```

I try to change it in `useEffect` in `App.tsx`, but it does not work.

Debugger shows that it reaches `setIsLoggedIn` but context is not changed

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (localStorage.getItem("token")) {
            appContext.setIsLoggedIn(true);
        } else {
            
        }
    },[])
```

Comment: Is the context provider higher up the component tree than the context consumer?

Comment: Yeah, just found it myself